# what happened to the biopython tag?

Tags: support, tags, tagging

What happened to the [biopython] tag? Bioinformatics stack exchange says 0 related question to it? Is it normal? I saved a biopython tag in one of my question filters so it was working once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. But it is surprising. Unused tags, tags that exist but are not actually used in any questions, are automatically removed by the system at regular intervals. So it is entirely possible that the tag did exist, as you remember, but has since been deleted because it wasn't used.

I see my fellow moderator, @M__ added it to a question recently which should mean it is now available again and won't be deleted unless it is removed from all questions again. I also added it to another I just found.

I don't know how or why this happened. I admit I don't personally pay much attention to that particular tag as I don't use biopython much, but it is surprising that we only have one question with the tag given how often we get biopython questions. So just tag any appropriate questions with it and we should be fine moving forward.

Comment: did on a couple of questions think 2 or 3 now I get the : "You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved."

Comment: That's OK, @pippo1980, it's better not to do too many edits at once anyway since that will just flood the front page with old questions because they were retagged.

Comment: @pippo1980 it was more like 6 or 7 edits :) But I have now approved them so you should be ready again. Just please don't add "with Biopython" to the question title if it wasn't there. Just because the OP happened to use biopython doesn't mean that is the only tool they are interested in.